# I'm making tic-tac-toe and updating array state on click array gets updated but doesn't update html box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, tic-tac-toe

I made arr as a state and updated in Box.js on handleClick when I log it on console it updates the state perfectly. but doesn't render html
it is supposed to update arr and re-render all arr dependent variables
//Board.js

```
import React from 'react'

import Box from './Box'
import './Board.css'

function Board() {
  //array of null grid
    const [arr, setArr] = React.useState(Array(9).fill(null))
  //check if current player is X
    const [isXTurn, ,setIsXTurn] = React.useState(true)
  //all props as object
    const props={arr,setArr,isXTurn,setIsXTurn}
    
  //array as Box element
  const arrayEle = arr.map((ele,i)=>(<Box {...props}  value={ele} index={i} key={i}/>))

  return (
    <div className='board'>
      {arrayEle}
      {arr}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Board;
```

//Box.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Box.css'
function Box(props) {
  //style as x & o
  const style = props.value==='X'? 'box x': 'box o'
  
  function handleClick(){
    if(props.value)
      return
    console.log(props)
    props.setArr(prevArr=>{
      const updatedArray = prevArr
      updatedArray[props.index] = (props.isXTurn?'X':'O')
      return updatedArray
    })
  }
  return (
    <button className={style} onClick={handleClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Box;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are mistakenly using `setArr()` function.
To invoke `setArr()` correctly in order to update state, you have to return a new value inside this function, not the same as previous one.

```
 props.setArr(prevArr=>{
      const updatedArray = prevArr
      updatedArray[props.index] = (props.isXTurn?'X':'O')
      return updatedArray
    })
```

In your code up here, you assigned `prevArr` to the const `updatedArray` and return it. But you should know cloning object in a javascript is a bit tricky.

You just cloned `prevArr` shallowly. So internally, `updatedArray` is exactly still same value as `prevArr`. So even though you changed the keys or values inside of it, it only refers to the same value and that's because your `setArr()` doesn't recognize change.

So, you should clone deeply the `prevArr` and return it.

I just googled and attach a reference that would be helpful for you

[The Best Way to Deep Copy an Object in JavaScript](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-best-way-to-deep-copy-an-object-in-javascript--cms-39655)